# Autotools/libtool link library with libstdc++ despite -stdlib=libc++ option passed to configure

Tags: c++11, clang, autotools, libtool, glog

I'm trying to build google-glog on Mac OS X 10.8, using following options:

./configure CXX='clang++' CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++'

Despite that the library gets linked with libstdc++.

Why, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's better to put 'dialect' and runtime flags in the compiler variable, since it will use those flags for linking - not just source compilation: `CXX="clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"`

Save `CXXFLAGS` for things like `-W -Wall -O2 -march=xxx`, etc.

Comment: I noticed that on macOS when building for iOS, I cannot append the `stdlib=libc++` to CXX with `clang++`. Must append it to CC with `clang` instead. Otherwise Autotools would fail to configure the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that you could use the build variable

```sh
LIBS+="-stdlib=libc++"
```

Seems to me a better place than the compiler variables.